# Find hiera config by pattern

Tags: namespaces, config, puppet, hiera

Given the following example hiera config:

```
my_company::app1:
 - something

my_company::app2:
 - something else

database:
 - [db config ...]
```

Is there a way to iterate over all entries in namespace `my_company`? For example create a file for each app. The main constraint is that I need to process only the entries which belong to `my_company`. I guess the way to do this would be merging all such entries into one big hash, but is there a way to keep them in separate entries and do something like `hiera('my_company::*:')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, not possible.

Rather easy to make it a hash though:

```
my_company:
  app1:
    - something
  app2:
    - something else
```

Then $data = hiera('mycompany') gives you all the data.

```
$app1 = $data['app1']
$app2 = $data['app2']
```

And so on.